# Processing of a TCP packet

Tags: sockets, tcp, operating-system, ip

I am wondering what is happening between the creating a `TCP` packet and a `[Ethernet[IP[TCP-packet]]]` leaving the network adapter.

When i use for example a `TCP` program and want to send a single packet ( or could be more in fact `TCP` using byte streaming).

So i set up in any language a function called `socket(...);`

So my OS, refering to any documenation, creating me an interface with a specified port on which I can receive and send data over.

And if I create a TCP package (for example `sendto(...)`, it will be send to the socket.

But what kind processes are done now [1], until my packet will leave the network adapter with an `Ethernet + IP Header`?

[1]: Where are the following steps happening (OS/Network adapter) and how does it exactly work?

Hope you understand me.. and please correct me if I missunderstood something wrong.

Comment: Too broad and off topic. You're asking for a complete description of TCP. See RFC 793, or a good book. NB the term is 'packet', not 'package'.

Comment: It's not about the description of TCP, it's about the processes between of a packet ;) leaving the network adapter!

Comment: So it's a description of Ethernet then. Still too broad, and still off topic.

Comment: I am not talking about the specification of Ehernet/TCP or whatever.. I am asking about the processes until a packet leaving the network adapter.